# Updating model in angular doesn't cause updating components variables in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with understand why Angular doesn't decorate variables in my component if I update it in controller:
`ctrl.myVar.attr = "decorated_" + ctrl.myVar.attr;`
after click on button in following plunker example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/cV18oB64oqiO9fYHrhCz?p=preview

Comment: `ctrl.myVar.attr = "decorated_" + ctrl.myVar.attr;` is being called **once**, when the controller is instantiated.  Updating the variable doesn't cause the component or it's controller to be re-instantiated or run again, so that line is never executed again.

Comment: @pumbosha, Actually the value is changing. What exactly you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$onChanges` life-cycle hook to react to changes on a one-way bound attribute:

```
app.component("mycomp", {
  template: "Hello {{$ctrl.name}}<br/>",
  bindings: {
    myVar: "<myvar"
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.$onChanges = function(changeObj) {
        if (changeObj.myVar) {
            this.name = "decorated_" + changeObj.myVar.currentValue;

        }
    }
  }
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/NAeNDwE8HMcggnRQThoq?p=preview)

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference -- Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear. But I am try to give answer what I understand.

Angular doesn't decorate variables in my component while update. Because You didn't call component in `changeAttrs` function. Please call component into function to do so.